# What happens when n is lower than r.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have 3 objects and we want to find a general formula counting how many times they can combine producing unique combinations.

For n number of different objects and r the length of the output: $C(n,r)  = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$.

What happens when n is lower than r?

Comment: The most usual definition is that $n \choose r$ is $0$ when $r \gt n$.  You can't choose $r$ objects out of $n$ in any ways at all.

Comment: $C(x,r)=x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-r+1)/r!$ is a polynomial of degree $r$ so it has $r$ zeroes. Namely, $C(x,r)=0$ when $x$ is an integer and $0\le x\le r-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be like selecting 5 objects from 4 objects, which is not possible since there are only 4 objects, or in other words, 0 ways to select. It is the same when selecting r objects from n objects when n<r.

Comment: But can't we select the same object multiple times?Or is it not allowed?

Comment: Yes, it isn't allowed, just like you can't pick up an object when you've already picked it up and haven't put it down yet.